# JQuery plugin not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

So I have this plugin http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jRating
I downloaded it and tried it on a new blank page just to see if I can do it. It worked.
The problem now is I put this plugin on my site and did the EXACT things as I did in the blank page, but this time the plugin is not working. Is it because I'm using the original jquery functions on the actual site or something?
Cant upload all my files online .. but here are the important parts

This is the imports

```
<!-- styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/general.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/place-event.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/homepage.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/css-buttons.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/colors.css"/>

<!-- plugin jRate -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugin/jrate/jquery/jRating.jquery.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/jrate/jquery/jRating.jquery.js"></script>

<!-- scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/removeTextClick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

This is the jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#abso").hide();
    $("#close").hide();


    $("#places-feed").load("eventPictures.html");
    $("#comments").load("commentsOnEvent.html");
    $("#insert-activity").load("newsFeed.html");
    $("#list-friends-feed-link").load("friendsCount.html");
    $("#notify").load("notificationCount.html");
    $("#list-groups-feed-link").load("groupsCount.html");


    $("#list-friends-feed-link").click(function(){ //start click

        $("#abso").load("listFriendsFeed.html");
        $("#abso").slideDown("600", function(){});
        $("#close").slideDown("600", function(){});

    }); //end click

    $("#list-pictures-feed-link").click(function(){ //start click

        $("#abso").load("picFeed.html");

        $("#abso").slideDown("600", function(){});
        $("#close").slideDown("600", function(){});
    }); //end click

    $("#list-groups-feed-link").click(function(){ //start click

        $("#abso").load("listGroupsFeed.html");

        $("#abso").slideDown("600", function(){});
        $("#close").slideDown("600", function(){});
    }); //end click

    $("#notify").click(function(){ //start click

        $("#abso").load("notifications.html");

        $("#abso").slideDown("600", function(){});
        $("#close").slideDown("600", function(){});
    }); //end click

    $("#upload-pic-place-gallery").click(function(){ //start click

        $("#abso").load("uploadPicPlaceGallery.html");

        $("#abso").slideDown("600", function(){});
        $("#close").slideDown("600", function(){});
    }); //end click

    $("#close").click(function(){ //start click

        $("#abso").slideUp("600",function(){});
        $("#close").slideUp("600",function(){});
    }); //end click


    // this block is for jRate plugin

    $(".ratings").jRating();

    // ---



});


</script>
```

finally this is some of the code that includes the div in the html that the plugin uses

```
<div id="the-place-event-div"> <!-- the place event div start -->

<div id="for-top-box"> <!-- for top box start -->
<a>
<img src="images/welcome.png"/>
</a>

<div id="place-description"><p>where awesomeness meets awesome</p> <!-- place description start -->
<p id="date-time">Date:<a>21/08/2010</a> Time:<a>07:00am</a></p>

<div class="ratings" data="12_1"> <!--rating div start -->



</div> <!-- ratings div end -->



 </div> <!-- place description end -->



</div> <!-- for top box end -->
```

Comment: Could you link to your site or a page which *should* work but doesn't? We can't telepathically extract useful information out of vague questions (yet).

Comment: Are you getting any script errors? If you are using Firefox then check in FireBub console whether its showing any errors.

Comment: @rahul no I dont get any error messages .. I checked with firebug

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding a reference to your plugin before refering to jQuery file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/jrate/jquery/jRating.jquery.js"></script>
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanx it worked :) .. but the problem now is its not showing stars icons .. It only shows a yellow bar

Comment: You might not be having the image in the right directory. Please check with Firebug Net tab whether you are getting any 404 Error.